# Can the Google Cloud API be used to perform punctuation restoration on text?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, nlp, punctuation

Google Cloud API may perform punctuation restoration when doing speech recognition  (https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/automatic-punctuation). 
Can the Google Cloud API be used to perform punctuation restoration on text?

Comment: Even if Google’s omniscience can add some punctuation, beware that isn’t necessarily the correct punctuation. Eats shoots and leaves. Eats, shoots, and leaves. Eats shoots, and leaves.

Comment: @barny Welcome to the field of natural language processing, where sometimes humans disagree on the gold annotations.

Comment: I’m not sure what you’re trying to say: are you agreeing with me?

Comment: @barny yes, I agree with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use [enableAutomaticPunctuation](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/automatic-punctuation) 
to add punctuation to recognition result hypotheses. This feature is only available in [some languages](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/languages) so setting this for requests in other languages has no effect at all. The default 'false' value does not add punctuation to result hypotheses. This is currently offered as an experimental service, complimentary to all users. In the future this may be exclusively available as a premium feature.

Comment: Thanks, can the input be text instead of speech in order to be able to use enableAutomaticPunctuation?

Comment: No, enableAutomaticPunctuation is for Speech-to-Text. For Text-to-Speech you can use [SSML](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/ssml) to allow customization in your audio response by providing details on pauses, and audio formatting for acronyms, dates, times, abbreviations, etc

Comment: thanks, I guess it means  the Google Cloud API cannot be used to perform punctuation restoration on some  text given by the user?

Comment: No, maybe you can try [deep-auto-punctuation](https://github.com/episodeyang/deep-auto-punctuation)